# QOpenGLtexture number of layers

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I'm working with GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY and QOpenGLTexture on Qt. I was wondering if there is any limitation on the number of layers with this kind of textures? I want to have 81 x 81 layers, but somehow it only works now with 81 x 25 layers. There is no segmentation fault I only get a black screen rendered instead of the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit. You can query the limit by a call to

```
GLint maxLayers;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, &maxLayers);
```

which is guaranteed to be at least 256.

If you request too many layers (or a texture that is not supported for any other reason) then an appropriate error will be generated. You can query the error with `glGetError`.

Comment: Thanks! that was it! so the limit for the layer is the same as the limit for the depth if I use GL_TEXTURE_3D?

Comment: @user3178756: no. The maximum supported depth of `GL_TEXTURE_3D` is `GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE`.